# Cordova Share Data between Apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a suite of Cordova-based apps that have the need to store data in a spot outside of the app's sandbox so other apps can read it.

I've taken a look at two plugins, [`cordova-plugin-secure-storage`](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage) and [`cordova-plugin-ios-keychain`](https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-ios-keychain). Neither explicitly mention that the storage being used can be accessed outside of the running app's scope.

I've tried my luck with `cordova-plugin-secure-storage` and was not able to share between two apps on Android; even though the store had the same name, the keys differed between the apps. That's OK -- I can store the file externally on Android.

My question is, am I wasting my time looking into keychain plugins to cover iOS? If so, any suggestions, or easier implementations?

Comment: @HassanShahzad - Not yet. Got side-tracked for 6 months!

Comment: Where you able to implement this without keychain plugins?